# Placing a graph on a 2d array

Tags: python, graph

I have a graph that consists of nodes and connections. Each node has a list of every other node it is connected to, like the object:

```
class Node():
  def __init__(self):
    self.connections = []
  def connect(self, node):
    self.connections.append(node)
    node.connections.append(self)
```

This is a simplified version of my node class. These nodes are connected in a tree-like structure - no loop connections. How would I go about turning a graph like

a-b   /f /h
 \c-d-e-g

into a 2d array like

```
[[a,b,f,h],
 [c,d,e,g]]
```

The array doesn't have a size limit but the array produced should be somewhat condensed. Extra nodes can be created to be used as filler if it is required.
This is the opposite of what questions that ask for a maze to be converted into a graph are asking for.

Comment: Are all the letters used contiguously from a to z? In that case you can swap the letters with numbers, use the array index to identify the node and then put in the node's children on that index in the array.

For your example:
[[b,c],[],[d],[e],[f,g],[],[h],[]]

Comment: The letters were only a representation of the nodes; in my program, each node has a unique int id bigger than 0 (not starting from it, not following any meaningful pattern). I don't think the solution you gave me is what I want, each connecting nodes must touch each other on the grid but touching nodes don't have to be connecting. The grid represents a maze.

Comment: For a tree of reasonable size, it seems like there are a lot of inequivalent ways to pack it into a maze-like array. If I have a-b-c-d, should I turn it into [[a,b],[c,d]]? Or into [[b,c],[a,d]]? Both ways seem to fit your rules.

Comment: Choose randomly or just pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Work out preference order of direction (N,E,S,W)
2. For any node with more than 4 connections:

   1. Add new 'connection' node
   2. While overflowing node has more than 4 connections
   3. If node not parsed and not just created node
   4. Disconnect from overflowing node
   5. Connect to new node
3. Place start node at 0,0
4. Set current node to one done last
5. For each connecting node

   1. If direction would prefer empty?
      Y: Place node in space, goto 4
   2. Repeat for all other preferences in order
   3. If all connections full, undo all and return bad